# I can't open snap programs

Tags: updates, snap, update-manager, 23.04, snap-store

I am kidna new to ubuntu and I recently updated ubuntu from 22.04 to 22.10 and then to 23.04 before i upgraded it to 23.04 everything worked fine as usual but after upgrading it all the snap progrms  that were installed before not working any more,when i open the apps i get either this error:

```
Cannot locate base snap core20 No such file or directory
```

Or i get this error  when i try to open vscode for example :`command code not found , but can be installed with : sudo snap install code`

When i try to install the app (vscode for instance) i get: `snap "code" is already installed`

Also the same problem for libra office i can't open any of libra software

Comment: Remove the snap and install it again. `sudo snap remove code` then `sudo snap install code`

Comment: I tried this it says 'sudo code is already installed